# Complex grammar question

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, punctuation

Do the words “direct physical” modify the word “damage” in the following phrase “direct physical
loss or damage”?

Since “loss” and “damage” are stated in the disjunctive by the use of “or” I suspect the “damage is not modified by “direct physical”. I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm _sure_ this has been covered before, but 'blue squares and triangles' and 'blue squares or triangles' are both notoriously ambiguous.

Comment: It's ambiguous, but in my opinion "damage" *is* modified by "direct physical". (In the context of, say, an insurance policy I would read it as "direct physical [loss or damages]".)

Comment: Context-free phrases, or those taken out of context, are generally meaningless in English which is heavily reliant upon context. A sentence or two describing the context and a sentence of two either side of the example would probably be helpful.

Comment: Direct physical loss or physical damage; direct physical-loss, or damage; or direct [physical] loss or damage, slightly modified from what @nnnnnn commented.

Answer (score 0):

Both modify *damage*. It refers to damage that is both direct and physical. The damage is direct, and it's also physical.

Both adjectives seem like clutter. I especially wonder why *direct* is needed. What physical damage isn't direct?

Comment: "What physical damage isn't direct?" Suppose I set your alarm clock this evening to wake you up tomorrow morning but I don't tell you. When the alarm goes off, you are so startled that you leap out of bed much more suddenly than usual, you fall down, and you break your nose. I think one can say in this situation that I've indirectly but physically damaged you.